# MVC Routing w/Virtual Directory

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, iis-6, directory, virtual

I'm having a lot of issues with MVC routing on IIS6.  Lets say my virtual directory is "xyz".  If I go to http://example.com/xyz, then it defaults correctly to my home controller.  The routing is all default.  But navigating to http://example.com/xyz/home/index gives a 404, all other pages also give a 404.

Also, I should mention that this server has Siteminder on it.  Just incase anyone has worked with MVC & Siteminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The siteminder dll was set to "verify if file exists".  Once unchecked, all worked properly, including siteminder.